# PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController appearing in simulator but not in real device

Tags: ios, swift

I have configured Apple Pay for the app and I have written code as follows. `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` appearing in simulator but not in real device.

```
func makePaymentwithApplePay()  {
 let paymentItem = PKPaymentSummaryItem.init(label: strRequestedSlot, amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: amountToBePaid))
        let paymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.amex, .discover, .masterCard, .visa, .interac]

        if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: paymentNetworks) {
            let request = PKPaymentRequest()
            request.currencyCode = "USD" // 1
            request.countryCode = "US" // 2
            request.merchantIdentifier = "“merchant.com.zipstored"// 3
            request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.capability3DS // 4
            request.supportedNetworks = paymentNetworks // 5
            request.paymentSummaryItems = [paymentItem] // 6
            if Stripe.canSubmitPaymentRequest(request),
               let paymentAuthorizationViewController =             PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request) {
                print("Hello I am In")
                paymentAuthorizationViewController.delegate = self
                present(paymentAuthorizationViewController, animated: true)
            } else {
                // There is a problem with your Apple Pay configuration
            }
        }
        else {
            displayDefaultAlert(title: "Error", message: "Unable to make Apple Pay transaction.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add In-App purchase to the Capabilities of the application?

Comment: @andromedainiative this is ApplePay,  not IAP.